# At which point do we take the value of impedance to tune an antenna?

Tags: antenna, electromagnetism, impedance-matching, pcb-antenna

I am a beginner in antenna design and tuning.

I want my antenna to have a resonant frequency of 2.45GHz for low-energy Bluetooth communication, and I want to know what to consider for the matching process.

I have made some measurements of my antenna with a NanoVNA. I have a resonance frequency of 2.28GHz and at this frequency, I have an impedance of 47.8-7.06j.

Can I take the value of this impedance at this frequency for the matching process or do I have to take the value of impedance at 2.45GHz?

Where should I take the value of impedance for tuning?

Comment: Generally, it is at the "base" of the antenna that measures would be taken where the screw is. It is your "reference plane". But you can define it where it is the easier. Also at the frequency center of use.

Comment: Did you read this ? https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/602730/tuning-an-antenna-using-a-nanovna-smith-chart-and-impedance-readings

Comment: Thanks, i see the suggestion in your link